# Is it possible in Chrome to have within one window, different tabs where each tab is from a different profile? If so, how?

Tags: google-chrome

Is it possible in Chrome to have within one window, different tabs where each tab is from a different profile? If so, how?

I thought I might have had something like it with an extension some time back.

Comment: I highly doubt something like this exists through an extension for the simple reason that 2 profiles occupy different folders on your harddisk, You can open multiple profiles and they open as separate windows, and then drag any window to another window, but that essentially moves one tab from one profile to another. With the new group functionality you can then group tabs to one group and give them a name and colour, but essentially its still one profile.

Comment: @LPChip ah I think you're right.. it was a cookie based tab thing..the extension that I had..  Also I Was going to make my question just the first paragraph but supseruser forced me to add stuff to it for "quality" reasons so I threw in the second paragraph!

Comment: Try the extensions [SessionBox](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/sessionbox-multi-login-to/megbklhjamjbcafknkgmokldgolkdfig?hl=en) and [MultiLogin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/multilogin/ijfgglilaeakmoilplpcjcgjaoleopfi?hl=en).

Answer (score 1):

When you open multiple profiles in Chrome, each profile is opened as a new window.

You can create a new tab and copy the url from one tab to the other.

And with the tab group feature, you can group all tabs from a profile together and give them a name and color for easier distinction.

Comment: You write "Given that you can drag a tab from a window to another tab, " <-- what do you mean by this?

Comment: If I drag a tab to another window then it only goes into there if that other window is the same profile.   If I try to drag a tab onto another tab then it doesn't it just looks at it as reordering tabs

Comment: Ah, indeed. You can't do this apparently. I'm mostly using Vivaldi, and there you can do it. I suppose you can still open a new tab in the other profile and copy/paste the url over.